# How can I extract the longitude and latitude from a text file?

Tags: parsing, filter, grep

I have a text file called iplocation.txt

```
   {"ip":"222.255.27.184","country_code":"VN","country_name":"Vietnam","region_code":"HN","region_name":"Hanoi","city":"Hanoi","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Asia/Bangkok","latitude":21.0313,"longitude":105.8516,"metro_code":0}
   {"ip":"222.255.27.187","country_code":"VN","country_name":"Vietnam","region_code":"HN","region_name":"Hanoi","city":"Hanoi","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Asia/Bangkok","latitude":21.0313,"longitude":105.8516,"metro_code":0}
   {"ip":"222.255.27.45","country_code":"VN","country_name":"Vietnam","region_code":"HN","region_name":"Hanoi","city":"Hanoi","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Asia/Bangkok","latitude":21.0313,"longitude":105.8516,"metro_code":0}
```

I only want the coordinates. I need some help to get data looking something like this:

```
latitude 21.0313 longitude 105.8516
latitude 21.0313 longitude 105.8516
latitude 21.0313 longitude 105.8516
```

I know about grep and awk. However, I am a beginner. I have spent some time searching and experimenting with no luck so far. I have not yet found the way. Help!

Comment: Those lines are JSON  You might want to look at [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), which is designed for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in python.

If your file is an excel file

```python
import pandas as pd

files = [
    {"ip":"222.255.27.184","country_code":"VN","country_name":"Vietnam","region_code":"HN","region_name":"Hanoi","city":"Hanoi","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Asia/Bangkok","latitude":21.0313,"longitude":105.8516,"metro_code":0},
    {"ip":"222.255.27.187","country_code":"VN","country_name":"Vietnam","region_code":"HN","region_name":"Hanoi","city":"Hanoi","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Asia/Bangkok","latitude":21.0313,"longitude":105.8516,"metro_code":0},
    {"ip":"222.255.27.45","country_code":"VN","country_name":"Vietnam","region_code":"HN","region_name":"Hanoi","city":"Hanoi","zip_code":"","time_zone":"Asia/Bangkok","latitude":21.0313,"longitude":105.8516,"metro_code":0}
]

object = {
    "latitude": 123, # Here I am creating an object, these are example values in the key,value pair
    "longitude": 123
}

final_output = []
for file in files:
    object["latitude"] = file['latitude']
    object["longitude"] = file['longitude']
    final_output.append(object)

df = pd.DataFrame(final_output)
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\saved.csv") # This will save it to your downloads folder, or just replace the path to anything else

print(final_output)
```

**Result:** File opened up in excel.

[image: Screenshot]